# A generalization of Hurwitz group

Tags: group-theory, reference-request, combinatorial-group-theory

Ignoring its geometric origin, a Hurwitz group might be defined abstractly by a non-trivial finite group which can be generated by elements $x$ and $y$ such that $x^2=y^3=(xy)^7=1$. I am wondering if there is any study on finite groups replacing $(2,3,7)$ by a triple of prime integers $(p,q,r)$, i.e. finite groups generated by elements $x$ and $y$ satisfying $x^p=y^q=(xy)^r=1$ for primes $p,q,r$.

Comment: What would you like to know about these groups? Even for the Hurwitz group, there are infinitely many options.

Comment: @MoisheKohan Well, if we name such finite group by $G$, I am mostly interested in any study on "moduli space of $G$-bundles" (on some base).

Comment: Then I would say, there is nothing in the literature on this subject. You would be the first to explore.